# printing null values in hive while declaring the column as decimal

Tags: hadoop, hive

I declared column as decimal.The data looks like this.

4500.00
5321.00
532.00

column name : area Decimal(9,2)

but in Hive it shows like this:

NULL
NULL

If I declare the column as a string it works fine. But I need it in decimal only.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be problem with the external table's delimiter mismatch.

I hope you might have configured different delimiter rather than the actual delimter exist in the file in case if you are using the external table.

Please try to find the actual delimiter and alter the table using the below command,

`alter table <table_name> set SERDEPROPERTIES ('field.delim' = '<actual_delimiter>');`

Comment: @illakya, were you able to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In create table statement

for example

```
CREATE TABLE figure(length DOUBLE, width DOUBLE, area DOUBLE) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

You replace '\t' by actual delimiter from your data file.

Comment: @illakya ramesh : Rather than recreating the table again as mentioned here.., Altering the table properties like #hserus said is appropriate..